# Merge whatsapp accounts

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have been using one WhatsApp number up until I went into another country where I started using a new number. 
In a new number I was joined into different groups and since WhatsApp allows one number per device I could not use old one. Now I want to merge my new number to my old WhatsApp account and have a single one.

Is that possible? I contacted their support and they have not answered yet.

I have both Sim cards in one phone

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this works (I didn't find anything in WhatsApp FAQ describing your situation) but you could try settings -> account -> change number from your old account, choosing the new number. There could be two problems: WhatsApp doesn't allow to merge two accounts this way or the account connected to the new number could be deleted and substituted by the old one.

Comment: I knew of that but was not sure whether it'll merge or do funny things like you said.  Thanks for comments

Comment: If You have titaniumbackup you can easily use  two nos for whatsapp.Just set different 'active data profile' for both nos. and you are done.you may set/keep the current sim as default profile and create a new profile and the use it for your old sim.In TB create a new profile->activate>backup/restore>whatsapp>specialfeatures>storage>enable'multiple profiles'for this app.

Comment: I'm not following here. Am not WhatsApp maverick and don't understand to tie together

Answer (score 1):

you can change the numbers by going into Settings>>Account>>Change Number.
Here you can Change Number form A to B and you wont loose your chats(data).
Also you can select an option if you want you contacts to get notification about this change.

Answer (score 0):

whatsapp now allowing users to change mobile number without loosing data. 
If you are ok to loose 1 whatsapp data, you can keep another. Just change your number and enjoy your whatsapp