# Merge 2 WhatsApp Accounts into one new fresh number

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, android-11, oneplus

I alraedy found questions like this: [Merge whatsapp accounts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128821/merge-whatsapp-accounts)

But there were no significant answers or scenarios which fit exactly my use case...

So my question is, is there any possibility (I have a OnePlus 8 Pro with Dual-Sim and DualApp) to merge BOTH accounts from my current setup to ONE new number and still have all chat-history?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying WhatsApp chat history to new Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241431/copying-whatsapp-chat-history-to-new-android)

Comment: @alecxs I don't know if I'm feeling comfortable doing what you described in that question. I don't have any experience in this stuff. the last time I was doing stuff like this was with Android 2.3 and flashing MIUI to an HTC Desire S. Can I lose my data?

Comment: yes there is a risk when uninstalling WhatsApp. -k flag should keep app data, but I have no experience. Kindky refer to xda thread for further support

Comment: You might want to clarify if you (1) want to have both numbers *actively* sharing chat and accessible on one/both number, or (2) just want to merge chat history from one account to another and only use the new number (the old account is ignored afterward).

Comment: @AndrewT. I just want to merge 2 chat-histories from 2 seperate numbers/accounts into one account and then changing to a completely new fresh number. So just a one time merge. And actually it's only 2 chats from the one number. One group and one single-chat.

Comment: Noted, then I think alecxs' answer on the linked question might work, but the update to WhatsApp app might also break it.

Comment: if bootloader is already unlocked there is of course no risk as you can just backup everything straight from /data instead